# How to create a page in Code behind and navigate the main page to created page in Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I need to create a page in Code behind and navigate the main page to created page in Windows Store app

I tried this but its not working the black page is navigated

```
Page p1 = new Page();    
p1.Content = pdfViewer1;   
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page),p1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to a page created entirely in code behind is very tricky. I am not even sure it is possible to do (at least without some complex hack) This is due to the fact that Visual studio builds some classes behind the scene to ensure the navigation especially the class "XamlTypeInfoProvider" which is used to identify the pages to which navigation is possible.

According to me, the easiest way to navigate to a page created in code behind is to create a "normal" blank page and then to fill this blank page with content created in code behind.

```
   // create the page content in code: here it is in the variable pdfviewer
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1),pdfViewer);
```

and within the "blank page" use the OnNavigatedTo event to put the created page content on the screen

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        (this.Content as Grid).Children.Add( e.Parameter as UIElement);
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you're using the correct Frame object. From what you've provided, it looks like you need to use the "root" frame, much as is done when your main window is loaded in your app's OnLaunched override.

Here's an example of launching a secondary page from a main page.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage));
    }
}
```

Note that what you pass to Navigate is the type of the Page object, not an instance of it. Navigate will create an instance and navigate to it. The new page's Loaded handler can then connect up any additional content, such as the PDF viewer shown in your code. If necessary, you can pass arguments to the secondary page by using one of the other Navigate overloads.